# Plotly offline html graph, embedding it into Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have created a 3D graph in Plotly and saved it as an html as follows:

```
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='3D.html')
```

I have also created a dashboard in Dash, however my question is how do I add '3D.html' to my dashboard? (3D.html is saved locally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use

```
html.div([ html.Iframe(src.get_asset_url("plotly3D.html)])
```